# Custom FFC Cable Design

Tags: pcb, design, eaglecad, ffc

How do I design a custom FFC cable on Eagle? Company wants them made in-house but I am not sure how to go about designing them or where to start

Answer (score 0):

Identify suitable manufacturers. Download their design guides and capabilities documents. If you have an in-house MCAD designer ask them to help with creating a professional drawing to describe outline and tolerances, stiffener etc. As well as fitting your mechanical requirements, they should incorporate whatever requirements the connector datasheets specify. Maybe you can get a .dxf outline file to import into your EDA program. If you don't have an in-house mechanical draftsperson, find a well-done drawing from which to copy essential elements. Don't bother with GD&T style tolerancing.

If there is repeated flexing in  the cable, talk to to the engineers at the supplier(s) you intend to use.

Then you can do the usual PCB layout in Eagle, Kicad or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the manufacturer, a good one to start with is pcbway.

The manufacturer will tell you what layers you will need to design with. Usually a 2 or 4 layer stackup is sufficient. Some manufacturers may want you to define where the coverlay and or stiffener is (if you want stiffener, stiffener is usually always defined by the designer). These will require extra mechanical layers